# Trying to avoid varnish cache

Tags: python, caching, nginx, request, varnish

I'm trying to avoid the varnish cache from client side. With nginx 1.6.1 it works with adding a random url parameter (see X-XHR-Current-Location) so it doesnt get the "X-Cache":"HIT".

```
Server: nginx/1.6.1
Date: Fri, 04 Sep 2015 13:13:02 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 20762
Status: 200 OK
X-XHR-Current-Location: /shop.json?1441372381.857126?1441372381.854355
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
ETag: "de6da75aa7b7d6ce34bd736ccf991f36"
X-Request-Id: a39fc3b8d44687039a18499dd22a2c7d
X-Runtime: 0.371739
X-Rack-Cache: miss
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Varnish: 534989417
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from localhost:3128
Connection: close
```

but as soons as I hit with the request a nginx/1.8.0 Server the URL gets somehow striped (see X-XHR-Current-Location) and the random parameter gets removed. Also the "X-Cache" gets triggered and returns a "HIT".

```
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Fri, 04 Sep 2015 13:13:14 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3555
Status: 200 OK
X-XHR-Current-Location: /shop/301316.json
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
ETag: "2e88dffe16a385872368e19e0370a999"
X-Request-Id: 3404c637c6a499d8e32a6e5c243e4d69
X-Runtime: 0.065267
X-Rack-Cache: miss
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Varnish: 561085217 561069463
Age: 823
Via: 1.1 varnish
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache: MISS from localhost
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from localhost:3128
Connection: close
```

I guess thats also the reason I get old results sometimes. Is there any way I can avoid the "HIT" or also pretend to be a new URL for the nginx/1.8.0 servers?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Would have to see your vhost... but likely what you need to do is make sure you have $is_args$args in your proxy_cache_key directive. Also make sure the querystring is part of the vcl_hash on the Varnish side (though I thought this was default).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly I can't work on the server side thats why I'm trying to bypass it on the client side which works with nginx/1.6.1 but if I hit a nginx/1.8.0 server the random parameter doesn't do anything.